# Codename One - GifImage not supported

Tags: codenameone, animated-gif

I am developing a simple Android-Mobile-App that uses a Gif. It's a Maven project.

I have imported the [Animated-Gif-Support library](https://github.com/codenameone/AnimatedGifSupport/) and used the code form [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/animated-gif-support.html).

Unfortunately, when I paste the sample code into my project, Eclipse can't find the method and returns the error: GifImage cannot be resolved.

```
hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new ScaleImageLabel(GifImage.decode(getResourceAsStream("/giphy-downsized.gif"), 1177720)));
```

I have restarted Eclipse and refreshed the libraries, all to no avail.

Any suggestions?

---

Code from pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example.minhaagenda</groupId>
        <artifactId>minhaagenda</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.minhaagenda</groupId>
    <artifactId>minhaagenda-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <!-- Add your cn1lib dependencies to this section -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codenameone</groupId>
            <artifactId>codenameone-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
  <artifactId>minhaagenda-AnimatedGifSupport</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.example.minhaagenda</groupId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

<!-- INJECT DEPENDENCIES -->
    </dependencies>

    <!-- The following are profiles to cover special cases -->
    <profiles>

        <!-- A profile to install Codename One support libraries to your home directory
            if they aren't installed yet. -->
        <profile>
        <id>install-codenameone</id>
        <activation><file><missing>${user.home}/.codenameone/guibuilder.jar</missing></file></activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>

                                <target name="install-cn1">
                                    <available file="${user.home}/.codenameone/guibuilder.jar" property="codenameone.present"/>

                                    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.codenameone"/>
                                    <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/codenameone/tmpProject"/>
                                    <get src="https://www.codenameone.com/files/updates/UpdateCodenameOne.jar"
                                         dest="${user.home}/UpdateCodenameOne.jar"
                                         skipexisting="true"/>
                                    <java jar="${user.home}/UpdateCodenameOne.jar" fork="true">
                                        <arg value="${project.build.directory}/codenameone/tmpProject"/>
                                        <arg value="force"/>
                                    </java>
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </profile>
        <!-- A profile to add kotlin support.  Activated if the src/main/kotlin
            directory exists -->
        <profile>
            <id>kotlin</id>
            <activation>
                <file>
                    <!-- To enable Kotlin, add the following file to the project base dir -->
                    <exists>${basedir}/src/main/kotlin</exists>
                </file>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <kotlin.version>1.3.72</kotlin.version>
                <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
        
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-annotations-jvm -->
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains/annotations -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
                    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
                    <version>13.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.codenameone</groupId>
                    <artifactId>java-runtime</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>initialize</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <files>
                                        <file>${basedir}/codenameone_settings.properties</file>
                                    </files>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>compile</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <sourceDirs>
                                        <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                        <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                                    </sourceDirs>
                                    <args>
                                        <arg>-no-reflect</arg>
                                        <arg>-no-jdk</arg> <!-- No JDK -->
                                    </args>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>test-compile</id>
                                <goals> 
                                    <goal>test-compile</goal> 
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <sourceDirs>
                                        <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                        <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
                                    </sourceDirs>
                                    <args>
                                        <arg>-no-reflect</arg>
                                        <arg>-no-jdk</arg> <!-- No JDK -->
                                    </args>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        

        <profile>
            
            <id>javase</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>codename1.platform</name>
                    <value>javase</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <codename1.targetPlatform>javase</codename1.targetPlatform>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>java</executable>
                            <longClasspath>true</longClasspath>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-Xmx1024M</argument>
                                <!--<argument>-Xdebug</argument>
                                <argument>-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8888,server=y,suspend=n</argument>-->
                                <argument>-classpath</argument>
                                <classpath />
                                <argument>${exec.mainClass}</argument>
                                <argument>${cn1.mainClass}</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!-- 
                For running in simulator in process use:
                mvn cn1:java -P simulator
                            
                Fro running in simulator in forked process use:
                mvn cn1:simulator -P simulator
            -->
                
            <id>simulator</id>
            <properties>
                <codename1.targetPlatform>javase</codename1.targetPlatform>
            </properties>
            
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!--
                For sending iOS debug builds use:
                mvn cn:build -P ios-debug
            -->
            <id>ios-debug</id>
            <properties>
                <!-- Build server target type -->
                <codename1.targetType>iphone</codename1.targetType>
                
                <!-- Used for identifying native interfaces.  Should match correct subdirectory of native -->
                <codename1.targetPlatform>ios</codename1.targetPlatform>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!--
                For sending iOS debug builds use:
                mvn cn:build -P ios-release
            -->
            <id>ios-release</id>
            <properties>
                <!-- Build server target type -->
                <codename1.targetType>iphone</codename1.targetType>
                <codename1.production>true</codename1.production>
                
                <!-- Used for identifying native interfaces.  Should match correct subdirectory of native -->
                <codename1.targetPlatform>ios</codename1.targetPlatform>
                <codename1.appStoreBuild>true</codename1.appStoreBuild>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!--
                For sending Javascript builds use:
                mvn cn:build -P javascript
            -->
            <id>javascript</id>
            <properties>
                <codename1.targetType>javascript</codename1.targetType>
                <codename1.targetPlatform>javascript</codename1.targetPlatform>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!--
                For sending Android builds use:
                mvn cn:build -P android
            -->
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <codename1.targetType>android</codename1.targetType>
                <codename1.targetPlatform>android</codename1.targetPlatform>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!--
                For sending Windows UWP builds use:
                mvn cn:build -P uwp
            -->
            <id>uwp</id>
            <properties>
                <codename1.targetType>windows</codename1.targetType>
                <codename1.targetPlatform>win</codename1.targetPlatform>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!--
                For sending Windows desktop builds use:
                mvn cn:build -P windows
            -->
            <id>windows</id>
            <properties>
                <codename1.targetType>desktop_windows</codename1.targetType>
                <codename1.targetPlatform>javase</codename1.targetPlatform>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!--
                For sending Mac Desktop builds use:
                mvn cn:build -P mac
            -->
            <id>mac</id>
            <properties>
                <codename1.targetType>desktop_macosx</codename1.targetType>
                <codename1.targetPlatform>javase</codename1.targetPlatform>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>${basedir}/codenameone_settings.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.codenameone</groupId>
                <artifactId>codenameone-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-gui-sources</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate-gui-sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>cn1-process-classes</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compliance-check</goal>
                            <goal>css</goal>
                            <!--<goal>compile-javase-sources</goal>-->
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-test-artifact</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attach-test-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>


        </plugins>


    </build>

    
</project>
```

Comment: How did you import the support library? Are you using Maven or Ant? Notice that Maven is recommended.

Comment: Hi Shai ... I didn't do any imports. Generally, Java suggests the CN1 imports, but this time I couldn't find any. What is the syntax? I am using Maven on Arch Linux.

Comment: You need to add a maven dependency? That's what I meant. Did you download the cn1lib?
Did you try adding it via the GUI? What's inside the maven POM?

Did you refresh the maven POM in the IDE?

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded the library from the Settings-GUI. The dependency seems to be inside the pom.xml. I wasn't sure where exactly to look, so I have added the whole thing. Still not working, though.

Comment: After you did that did you click the maven refresh button in the IDE?
It should go and download the dependencies into the `~/.m2` directory hierarchy. There might be an error message there when you do a refresh.